# How to store hour:minute and skip seconds and milliseconds in a JPA entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to have Date just store till hour:minute and skip seconds and milliseconds in the following User entity

```
import jakarta.persistence.Basic;
import jakarta.persistence.Temporal;
import jakarta.persistence.TemporalType;

class User {

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    java.util.Date birthDate

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.time.LocalDate and type of this column in Database is Date.

If you set type in Database is Datetime, it will save yy-mm-dd 00:00:00.

But it's not a big problem, JPA will map it to field type in your class and work well.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wanted to store hour and minute but not more time Information.

Well it is not directly possible in JPA unless you are willing to Split the Information into several columns, using Embeddable.

If you are happy with using Hibernate propietary API you can create a socalled UserType.

This explains it quite well:
https://theodoreyoung.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/custom-user-types-with-jpa-and-spring/

Cheers Tom.